# How to disable gnu extensions for clang?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, clang

I've tried "-U__GNUC__", but the preprocessor's output still contains "__attribute__" or something like that. How to make the compiler discard those non-standard things? My OS is OS X 10.10 and when I run the compiler with option "-U__GNUC__", it complains:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:81:2:
 warning: 
   "Unsupported compiler detected" [-W#warnings]
#warning "Unsupported compiler detected"
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Most likely your systems C library headers contain this type of extensions.

Comment: I want to do some tests.

Comment: There is no way to disble them, `-U__GNUC__` won't do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You probably cannot do that.

You might try to compile with `clang -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -Werrors`; see [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#options-to-control-error-and-warning-messages); this should prohibit `__attribute__` in your user code, but still allow it in system headers.

Notice that according to standards, identifiers starting with `_` are implementation reserved and should not be used in standard conforming application code.

Hence your implementation (e.g. standard C or standard C++ library) can (and probably does) use them. And several `__attribute__`-s in *system* headers are useful for the optimizations done by the compiler e.g. the compiler can optimize your use of `malloc` because system headers probably declare `malloc` with `__attribute__((malloc))`, etc.